# Small (code-size) hash functions

Tags: hash

I am trying to implement a small encryption tool in as little code as possible as a learning exercise, and currently have managed to get everything to depend only on a HMAC construct. However, most hash functions I know (sha256, blake2) tend to be quite large when written out in Python. Are there any small hash functions that are safe to use in a HMAC setup?

Comment: [code-golf SHA-256](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/81195/82732). Quite amazing, right? When one ask as little as possible should be careful :).

Comment: If you want something truly tiny, might I suggest you base things on Speck instead?  You can do Speck-CMAC to do the MAC; to can use Speck in a different mode to encrypt (or just use Speck-CMAC to do everything)

Comment: @poncho Hm, I guess HKDF could be adapted to use CMAC as well?